# Jquery doesn't load content on first click

Tags: jquery, html

I have a short script which loads content of a given link into an element. The content depends on the id of the link clicked.
The problem I'm facing is that it never loads the content on the first click. I need to click on another main link and only then it loads. Let you show you what I've got:

```
<div class="mainTabs">
<ul>
  <li class="activeTab"><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
  <li id="secondTab"><a href="#certificates">Certificates</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabsContent">
  <div id="skills" class="tab active">
    {% include "./_skills.html" %}
  </div>
  <div class="tab" id="certificates">
    {% include "./_certsList.html" %}
  </div>
</div>
```

And Jquery is:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.textBox h3').load("{% url 'aboutme' %}");
$('.row li').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.activeSkill').removeClass('activeSkill');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('activeSkill');
  var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $('.textBox h3').load(link);
});
});
```

Let's say I click on 'Certificates'. The page below is not loaded at first, only if I click on another link then it loads. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Seems like you're missing part of your html. For the selector ".textBox h3" there is nothing with class textbox and h3

Answer (score 0):

Im struggling to understand this without a full example, but my interpretation of this is that the logic appears to be wrong :

The following line removes all 'activeSkill' classes from the DOM.

```
$('.activeSkill').removeClass('activeSkill');
```

The next line adds the 'activeSkill' class to the `<a>` under the `<li>` that was clicked... was that intended?

```
$(this).find('a').addClass('activeSkill');
```

Can you explain what the role of `activeSkill` is? Also shouldn't you be setting the `active` class on the selected tab `<div>`, and removing it from the currently active `<div>`?